# Prevent User From Unhiding Datasheet Columns

Tags: vba, ms-access, datasheet

I have hidden several columns in an access datasheet using the [ColumnHidden property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224064(v=office.11).aspx) like this example here:

```
ColumnName.ColumnHidden = true
```

This works great, but when I view the datasheet, the end user can unhide the column by "resizing" the space either side of where the column is hiding:

[image]

I have found a couple of hacks to resize the columns using the `ColumnWidth` property via vba on certain events vba etc. but I was wondering whether there is a simple way to disable this "resize" feature in the first place for hidden columns only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MouseUp event You can check if `ColumnHidden` of hidden column is false (user "resized" the column), hide it.

```
Private Sub Form_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
If Me.MyHiddenColumn.ColumnHidden = False Then
    Me.MyHiddenColumn.ColumnHidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - I never thought of that. That is simple and effective too. Excellent. Thank you.